# Apache Nifi PutFTP change extension of file

Tags: apache-nifi

I transform csv data to json and write that information to `PutFTP`, the extension of the file output is `csv` and not `json`. How can I override this information for the `PutFTP` processor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [`UpdateAttribute`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/) processor to change the *filename* attribute of the flowfile from `example.csv` to `example.json`.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that the `UpdateAttribute` worked well but struggled to find an expression that worked with it. After some testing and research I arrived at this solution.

```
${filename:substringBeforeLast('.'):append('.json')}
```

Answer (score 2):

A more dynamic answer when using `UpdateAttribute` is to use NiFi expressions to change the filename:

So to change `dynamc_name.txt` to `dynamc_name.json`

Set your NiFi  UpdateAttribute filename to:

```
${filename:substring(0,11).json}
```

---

[image]

```
Expression                                              Value

${filename:substring(0,1)}                              a

${filename:substring(2)}                                brand new filename.txt

${filename:substring(12)}                               filename.txt

${filename:substring( ${filename:length():minus(2)} )}  xt
```

Reference: https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.0.2/bk_expression-language/content/substring.html